# EditForm only submits on second enter

Tags: forms, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I built a simple chat widget for my SPA, and for some reason the input only submits from the second time I press `enter`. The first time, the focus shifts away from the input...somewhere. I have to click back into the input. Then I can press enter and it submits.

The form is just an `EditForm` with an `InputText` I bind to a value.

HTML part:

```
<EditForm Model="message" OnSubmit="SendMessage">
    <InputText type="text" @bind-Value="message" />
</EditForm>
```

C# part:

```
private string message = string.Empty;

private async Task SendMessage()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Send message " + message);
    await Service.SendMessage(message);
    message = string.Empty;
    StateHasChanged();
    Console.WriteLine("State has changed called");
}
```

Comment: replace `StateHasChanged()` with `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);` and make the method void.

Comment: Same problem (plus now the task gets killed before it can completely finish, throwing an exception). May I ask why make it `void` and use `InvokeAsync` instead of just calling `StateHasChanged()`?

Comment: about diff in calling StateHasChanged you can read here https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/16119 , if you let the method returning task you need to call it `@(async()=>await SendMessage())` on EditForm

Comment: Ha thanks for the link. Turns out I didn't even need to call it myself, as the method is part of the component itself and therefore automatically tells it to update. Unfortunately my original problem persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place a "submit" button within the EditForm component. This is how you submit a form.

The StateHasChanged method call is not necessary with UI events.

Hope this helps...

### Update:

The reason why the SendMessage method is not called the first time, whether you place a "submit" button or not, is that the “Form submission canceled because the form is not connected”. In the current context this occurs because you don't provide a model to the EditForm, I mean a real model such as the following:

```
 public class Comment
{
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

If you do that, and you should, then you'll get what you want...

Comment: I tried the same thing with a submit button with hidden attribute because I want the user to only use enter to send a message - with the same result: only the second press actually submits the form. Making it not hidden and clicking the button also needs two clicks to actually submit.  Edit: Also by convention, a form without submit button can submit with the default button (on desktop: enter), as long as it has only one input.